# Why can I not access a variable declared in a macro unless I pass in the name of the variable?

Tags: macros, rust, rust-macros

I have this macro:

```
macro_rules! set_vars {
    ( $($x:ident),* ) => {
        let outer = 42;
        $( let $x = outer; )*
    }
}
```

Which expands this invocation:

```
set_vars!(x, y, z);
```

into what I expect (from `--pretty=expanded`):

```
let outer = 42;
let x = outer;
let y = outer;
let z = outer;
```

In the subsequent code I can print `x`, `y`, and `z` just fine, but `outer` seems to be undefined:

```
error[E0425]: cannot find value `outer` in this scope
  --> src/main.rs:11:5
   |
11 |     outer;
   |     ^^^^^ not found in this scope
```

I can access the `outer` variable if I pass it as an explicit macro parameter.

Is this intentional, something to do with "macro hygiene"? If so, then it would probably make sense to mark such "internal" variables in `--pretty=expanded` in some special way?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, this is *macro hygiene*. Identifiers declared within the macro are not available outside of the macro (and vice versa). Rust macros are not C macros (that is, Rust macros are more than glorified text replacement).

See also:

- [The Little Book of Rust Macros](http://danielkeep.github.io/tlborm/book/mbe-min-hygiene.html)
- [A Practical Intro to Macros](https://danielkeep.github.io/practical-intro-to-macros.html#being-hygienic)
- [So, what are hygienic macros anyway?](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/5v8r8f/so_what_are_hygienic_macros_anyway/)

Comment: Is there a way to bypass it?

Comment: @ArtyomGevorgyan not that I'm aware of; pass in the name in that case.