# Passing nested struct field path as macro parameter

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I am fairly new to Rust, and I am having trouble getting the following code to compile:

```rust
#![feature(trace_macros)]

fn main() {
    #[derive(Debug)]
    struct Inner {
      value: u8
    }
    
    #[derive(Debug)]
    struct Outer {
      inner: Inner
    }
    
    let mut x  = Outer { inner: Inner { value: 64 } };
    
    /********/
    
    macro_rules! my_macro {
        ($field_path:expr, $v:expr) => {
            x.$field_path = $v;
        }
    }

    trace_macros!(true);    
    // my_macro!(inner, Inner { value: 42 }); // only works with $field_path:ident
    my_macro!(inner.value, 42); // expected output: x.inner.value = 42;
    trace_macros!(false);
    
    x . inner.value = 42; // works fine
    
    assert_eq!(42, x.inner.value);
}
```

I am getting the following errors:

```
error: unexpected token: `inner.value`
  --> src/main.rs:20:15
   |
20 |             x.$field_path = $v;
   |               ^^^^^^^^^^^
...
26 |     my_macro!(inner.value, 42); // expected output: x.inner.value = 42;
   |     --------------------------- in this macro invocation
   |

...

error: expected one of `.`, `;`, `?`, `}`, or an operator, found `inner.value`
  --> src/main.rs:20:15
   |
20 |             x.$field_path = $v;
   |               ^^^^^^^^^^^ expected one of `.`, `;`, `?`, `}`, or an operator
...
26 |     my_macro!(inner.value, 42); // expected output: x.inner.value = 42;
   |     --------------------------- in this macro invocation
   |

...
```

However, `trace_macro` seems to be able to expand `my_macro!`:

```
note: trace_macro
  --> src/main.rs:26:5
   |
26 |     my_macro!(inner.value, 42); // expected output: x.inner.value = 42;
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: expanding `my_macro! { inner . value, 42 }`
   = note: to `x . inner.value = 42 ;` <<< exactly what I am looking for
```

If I keep `$field_path` parameter as `ident`, I am simply getting `` no rules expected the token `.` `` , which I guess makes sense, because `.` is an operator.
What am I missing?

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0636803239b446163f8a001a84e7dbe4)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can I not access a variable declared in a macro unless I pass in the name of the variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53716044/why-can-i-not-access-a-variable-declared-in-a-macro-unless-i-pass-in-the-name-of)

Comment: @pretzelhammer correct me if I'm wrong, but if you switch `$field_path` type to `ident` and run the `my_macro!(inner, Inner { value: 42 });` line from my demo, it compiles and properly modifies `x`. I think the issue lies in the fact that `inner.value` contains the dot operator.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I think the issue lies in the fact that `inner.value` contains the dot operator.

That's exactly your issue. There isn't a single [fragment specifiers](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/macros-by-example.html#metavariables) that allows you to match `ident` and/or a [field access expression](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/field-expr.html). The issue with using `expr` ([expressions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions.html)) is that when expanded it essentially wraps in parenthesis, i.e. `x.(inner.value)`, which doesn't make sense and thus why you're getting an `` "unexpected token `inner.value`" ``.

However, you can indeed use `ident`, you just need to use [repetition](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/macros-by-example.html#repetitions) as well.

In short, instead of `$field_path:ident` then you do `$( $field_path:ident ).+`. Then to expand it, instead of `x.$field_path` then you do `x. $( $field_path ).+`.

```rust
macro_rules! my_macro {
    ($($field_path:ident).+, $v:expr) => {
        x.$($field_path).+ = $v;
    };
}

// Now both are allowed
my_macro!(inner.value, 42);
my_macro!(inner, Inner { value: 64 });
```

Comment: what about tuple e.g. `my_macro!(0.inner.value, 42);`

Answer (score 3):

The reason it doesn't work is because Rust macros operate on AST nodes, instead of tokens.

The AST for accessing a nested field looks like this (with a very loose syntax where parentheses denote an AST node): `(((x).outer).inner)`

You've set `$field_path` to be an `expr`, so it gets parsed like this: `((inner).outer)`. This is a valid expression that accesses the `outer` field of the `inner` variable.

Then, evaluating the macro produces something like: `((x).((inner).outer))`, which doesnt make sense.

Now, how to fix it?

The key is that the variable name (like `x` in this case) needs to end up "deep within" the AST of the expression that accesses the field. This makes it impossible to do it with any way of "passing in" a path as a macro argument.

What you can do is pass in a macro that builds the path expression:

```rust
macro_rules! my_macro {
    ($path:ident, $v:expr) => {
        $path!(x) = $v;
    }
}
macro_rules! inner_value {
    ($x:ident) => {
        $x.inner.value
    }
}

my_macro!(inner_value, 42); // expected output: x.inner.value = 42;
```

[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0a3e25e2b052ff988cc685d008c2ae60)

I'd consider doing this without macros though, for better readability. Depending on what you're doing, using a closure might work:

```rust
fn do_things(x: &mut Outer, path: impl Fn(&mut Outer) -> &mut u8){
    *(path(x)) = 42;
}

do_things(&mut x, |x| &mut x.inner.value);
```

[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fd201c85b9cf44045a447812e77cf619)

Comment: I appreciate the explanations, however it seems like macro repetitions that were suggested by @vallentin work better for my case.